# MS Access subquery performance

Tags: sql, ms-access

I use MS Access a lot as an ad-hoc data processing tool. One thing I've noticed is that using sub-queries in certain ways tends to have very bad performance with large tables.

For example, this query performs poorly:

```
SELECT TOP 500 EmployeeID FROM Employee
WHERE EmployeeID NOT IN
    (SELECT EmployeeID FROM LoadHistory
    WHERE YearWeek = '2015-26');
```

This version of the same query performs well:

```
SELECT TOP 500 EmployeeID FROM Employee
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM LoadHistory
    WHERE YearWeek = '2015-26' AND
        EmployeeID = Employee.EmployeeID);
```

And this other form of the same query also performs well:

```
SELECT TOP 500 Employee.EmployeeID
FROM Employee
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT EmployeeID FROM LoadHistory
    WHERE YearWeek = '2015-26') q
ON Employee.EmployeeID = q.EmployeeID
WHERE q.EmployeeID IS NULL;
```

For style reasons, I prefer the first form. I can't really understand why the optimizer doesn't generate the same plan for the first and second queries. Is there any logic to how the ACE optimizer is behaving here? Are there any other ways to slightly rewrite the first query so the optimizer can do a better job?

Answer (score 2):

`NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` are very similar . . . but not quite the same.

The semantics of `NOT IN` specify that it never returns true if *any* of the values are `NULL`.  That means that the subquery has to verify that this is true.

My guess is that this accounts for the different optimization schemes.  This is also why I prefer `NOT EXISTS` to `NOT IN`.  `NOT EXISTS` is more intuitive in the treatment of `NULL` values in the subquery.

Note:  You should *always* qualify column names when you use correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT TOP 500 EmployeeID
FROM Employee
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM LoadHistory
                  WHERE LoadHistory.YearWeek = '2015-26' AND
                        LoadHistory.EmployeeID = Employee.EmployeeID
                 );
```

The compiler *might* be smart enough to avoid this if you declare `LoadHistory.EmployeeId` as `NOT NULL`.

I should also mention that `NOT EXISTS` can take advantage of an index on `LoadHistory(EmployeeId)` or `LoadHistory(EmployeeId, YearWeek)`.  The `NOT IN` version can use `LoadHistory(YearWeek)` or `LoadHistory(YearWeek, EmployeeId)`.  Perhaps your indexes explain the difference in performance.

Answer (score 0):

It is the difference between `in` and `exists`. `Exists` evaluates to true the first time a sub-query matches a given condition. On the other hand, `in` would scan the entire table.

Comment: I think this would account for an up to 50% performance difference, but in this situation the difference is between instantaneous and about 10 seconds. Sorry I didn't include that information in the question.